# In Tennis why is zero called Love?

Tags: tennis

Ive heard many theories one being that a 0 looks like an egg and the french word for egg sounds like love and after time became just that, but this is just one theory. Does anyone know the actual reason why 0 in tennis is called love?

Comment: It's fairly obvious from (e.g.) various Wikipedia articles that there isn't one definitive reason, so voting to close this as opinion based.

Comment: Disagree with closing based on opinion based.  It is a question that _could_ have a valid answer.  It probably doesn't have a definitive one, though, and I'll downvote any answer that _is_ solely opinion.  However - it does have a clear duplicate, so that's the right close reason.